# Typescript extension class not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend my HTMLButtonElement interface by two methods. Specifically I want to modify the elements class list.

```
class BSHTMLButtonElement extends HTMLButtonElement {
    removeOutline(): void { this.classList.remove(...COLOR_LIST.map(i => `btn-outline-${i}`)); }
    setOutline(color: string): void { this.removeOutline(); this.classList.add(`btn-outline-${color}`); }
}

const tbxusername = document.getElementById("tbxusername") as BSHTMLInputElement;
tbxusername.setOutline("danger");
```

Then it compiles just fine and I get a runtime error like this:

```
tbxusername.setOutline is not a function
```

Is there a better way to extend the functionality of an HTMLElement than what I'm trying? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are forcing the type by casting it. You are saying that you know the element is `BSHTMLInputElement` but seems like during the runtime, it isn't.

Comment: Yes, i know that it is a HTMLInputElement. But how can I add functionality to it that normal HTMLInputElements do not have?